# Maximum Value of function f

Tags: functions

How can I find the maximum value of the function

\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2 + 2xy - 2x - 2y + 1  
\end{equation*}

where $x^2+y^2 \leq 2x$?

Comment: Consider Lagrange optimization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization

Comment: Use Lagrange multipilers, or just substitute the constraint into the objective function and use single-variable calculus.

Comment: I guess that we should observe that
$$
(x+y-1)^2-2y^2=x^2-y^2+1-2x-2y+2xy
$$

Comment: Can someone explain to me  Lagrange multipilers please?

Comment: @Poli http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $$x^{2}-y^{2}+1-2x-2y+2xy = (x+y-1)^{2}-2y^{2}$$

Subject to the constraint $(x-1)^{2}+y^{2} \leq 1$